# Using labels and openstreetmap in a graph with Bokeh serve

Tags: python, bokeh

I've created a graph with bokeh and added openstreetmap with the bokeh.tile_provider and CARTODBPOSITRON. I also added labels to the point data, but noticed the labels disappearing beneath the openstreetmap. Is there a way to put the labels 'above' or 'on top' in the graph?

I've tried to run my code without openstreetmap and the labels are visible. However, after adding the openstreetmap, the label disappear underneath the map.
Moving the f.add_layout(labels) above of underneath the f.add_tile(tile_provider) doesn't seem to work.

```
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, layout

source_o = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(label_o = ["DC-001", "DC-002", "DC-003"],                        
xdata_o = [461701.3717889148, 461752.3817861293, 461752.9975699731],
ydata_o = [6788398.566150362, 6788377.060072248, 6788376.785602528]))

tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)
f = figure(x_range=(461820, 461880), y_range=(6788100, 6788600),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator",
           plot_width=1400, 
           plot_height=400,
       tools="pan,wheel_zoom,reset")
label_f = LabelSet(x='xdata_o', y='ydata_o', text='label_o', source=source_o, level='glyph', x_offset=5, y_offset=5, render_mode='canvas')

f.add_tile(tile_provider)
f.circle(x='xdata_o', y='ydata_o', source=source_o, legend="Locaties DefoCube")
f.add_layout(label_f)

l = layout([f])

curdoc().add_root(l)
```

I there a way to bring the labels 'on top' of the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Actually I just noticed you were changing the render level. There is almost never a reason to do that. When I remove `level="glyph"` and let the labels use the standard annotation level (which is above all glyphs) then the labels show up on top (even with `render_mode="canvas"`)

---

This seems like a bug. Please file a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with all this information. In the mean time, setting `render_mode='css'` for the `LabelSet` seems to float the labels on top.

Alterntatively, the `text` glyph also works, but does not have the offset paramters that labels do:

```
f.text(x='xdata_o', y='ydata_o', text='label_o', source=source_o)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, removing the level="glyph" brings the labels on top.